# How to create a Search Help Exit Function Module, if it requires TABLES parameters but those are obsolete?

Tags: search, parameters, abap, function-module

Trying to create a Search Help Exit (to copy an old one actually).

My problem is that I can't declare Tables parameters for a function module (because they are obsolete and i can't get past the warning) BUT on checking by Function Module, an error tells me that I MUST use TABLES parameters - and every tutorial I found uses this method.

So is there a way to either:

1. Ignore the warning and use TABLES parameters or
2. Use CHANGING parameters and have the Function Module know i'm using those instead of the TABLES params?

[EDIT]: Actually the TABLES parameters can be used, it's just that you have to hit ENTER a lot of times

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `TABLES` parameters in this case, even though they are obsolete - otherwise the calling program (deep down in the SAP basis) would have to be adapted, and that in turn would break all existing value help exits at once. As you said, just keep on hitting the Enter key until you've confirmed all of the warnings.